# Unable to launch app in Android emulator: Stuck on 'Flutter: Launching...' and 'Waiting for observatory port to be available...'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm dealing with a very frustrating problem where **I am unable to launch my app with my Android emulator**. I am using **VS Code** and **Android Studio** for the emulator. It keeps getting hung up.

When I try to launch from **VS Code** (Run > Start Debugging), it hangs on `Flutter: Launching...`
[image]

When I try to launch from **Powershell** (`flutter run --verbose`), it hangs on Waiting for observatory port to be available...

```
[ +228 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +4 ms] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

Initially, going down some rabbit holes online led me to think my package/app id might be wrong. Here are what they are in all locations:

**android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
package="com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher">
```

**android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
package="com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher">
```

**android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
package="com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher">
```

**android/app/build.gradle:**

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
multiDexEnabled true
}

**android/app/google-services.json:**

```
"package_name": "com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher"
```

**android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/locationalertsapp/MainActivity.kt:**

```
package com.ceventures.app.locationalerts.cedric.eicher
```

**Things I have tried:**

- flutter clean
- Changing all names to com.example.locationalertsapp
- Clean boot emulator, increasing storage size, wipe data clean, trying other emulator devices
- Restarting my machine, upgrading flutter, deleting the flutter/bin/cache directory
- Updating Android Studio to the latest version

Any help is appreciated, this is driving me crazy! It just worked a few days ago!

Comment: Might be a red herring but are you running the very latest Android Studio. I had a similar problem with a late version of the emulator and had to go back a version or two. It seemed to be related to firebase use in my app. The very latest Android Studio, which I installed today, seems to work fine.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll try that and report back!

Comment: Sadly, no dice. I upgraded to the latest available and the issue is unchanged.

Comment: Hmm.... can't check back on what fixed it for me for about 12 hours. Sorry and all that. I will check this question again then to see if you have resolved it

Comment: Seems closing the emulator, using wipe data for that emulator in Android Studio and restarting the emulator fixed it for me.

Comment: Sadly no luck after trying that. I created an entirely separate base app (flutter create test_app) and had the same issue, so I'm guessing it must be something wrong with my flutter daemon or vs code/android studio setup. I'm considering just blowing them all away and completely reinstalling.

Comment: Very strange. I would have thought rebooting your PC and wiping the emulator data would cover all the bases. Maybe just use a physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED -- NOTE I AM OP**

So after a week of dealing with this, the following led me to getting things to finally work:

1. Doing a windows update
2. Switching to the flutter stable branch, and then doing flutter upgrade
3. Doing a cold boot of my emulator device
4. Resolving pubspec package issues and the `environment:` and `sdk:` versions worked for all the packages (if they don't, you'll be alerted)
5. Updating the following to the original `com.example.locationalertsapp`

   android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
   android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml
   android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

I really don't know why this all worked. I had to step away from this issue for a few days just because I couldn't handle it anymore and I felt like I was down rabbit hole after rabbit hole.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!